# How to do multi column sorting in jQuery DataTable?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables, jquery-plugins

How to do make multi-level sorting in jQuery Datatable. I want to sort my table first by Age and then messages.

Here what I am having-
Table with columns as `Name`, `Age`, `Messages` I want to first sort with `Age` then with `Messages`.
So if I sort with Age I should be able to perform next level sorting on message!! how it can be possible?

Code-

```
<table id="myTable" class="display table-striped">
                    <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name/th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Messages</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Jhon</td>
                        <td>21</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Kamran</td>
                        <td>22</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Maria</td>
                        <td>40</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Ritu</td>
                        <td>40</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Ram</td>
                        <td>40</td>
                        <td>8</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Sneha</td>
                        <td>30</td>
                        <td>8</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Akram</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Bhavesh</td>
                        <td>30</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myTable').DataTable( {
       columnDefs: [
                    {
                        orderData: [[1, 'asc'], [2, 'desc']]//sort by age then by messages
                    }
                ]
        } );
    } );
</script>
```

However, this is not working as I have expected! please help:(

Comment: It's just `order`, not `orderData`

Comment: oh I am sorry. But sir still I am not getting the desired result.
I want to sort by age then by messages, so as I am having 3 records of age 40, if I sort messages only these 3 should change there order